# How to efficiently remove repeated instances of the same text in a PDF?

Tags: pdf

This purchased PDF (that I didn't create) repeats the text, underlined in green, under each diagram. Undeniably, deleting each instance one by one is too inefficient! How can I delete this text synchronously, productively, at one fell swoop?

[image]

Comment: Normally you would make changes like this in the working document (probably made in InDesign). Otherwise you have to hack your way through editing directly in the PDF. Which application do you use?

Comment: @Wolff I didn't create this PDF though. Thus I don't think I possess "the working document"?  I'm using Adobe Acrobat DC.

Answer (score 1):

The only relatively quick way I see doing this in Adobe Acrobat DC (without use of a plugin) is to use the *Find/Replace* dialogue.

1. Use *Edit > Find* or press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to open the *Find* dialogue.
2. Enter or paste in the full sentence you want to remove in the *Find* field.
3. Click *Replace with* to unfold the *Replace with* dialogue.
4. Leave the *Replace with* field empty.
5. Click the *Replace* button to find the first instance.
6. Click the *Replace* button again to replace the found text with nothing.
7. Keep clicking the *Replace Next* button until no more instances are found.

Sadly this functionality is a bit simple and doesn't allow you to change all instances in one go.

This should remove the unwanted text, but leaves behind empty text frames. That shouldn't be a problem. If you want to remove the text frames as well, I'm afraid you need to manually select each box with the mouse and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>. Not a completely overwhelming task if you only have a few hundred diagrams.